# OnSelectStart doesn't work on Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

I have this code:

```
<div id="menu_blue" onSelectStart="show_and_hide()">
  ...
</div>
<div id="menu_red">
  ...
</div>

<script>
function show_and_hide()
{
    $("#menu_red").slideToggle("slow");
}
</script>
```

and my firefox version 38.0.5 doesn't want to do anything.
I know it could be replaced by `OnClick=""` but I want to know why firefox does't support this function.
Does anybody know?
Thank you.

Comment: "There are no standards that apply here." -- [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536969%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Looks like a non-standard IE thing.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using doing your click event handlers in HTML it is better to bind them on the document ready or load.

```
$(document).on("ready",function(){
 $("#menuBttn").on("click",function(event){

  })
})
```

Also you might find this useful, http://help.dottoro.com/ljwdpnva.php